# Passport check on a UK-EU-EU flight

Tags: transit, passports

I would go for a UK-EU-EU flight: UK-Germany-Hungary. In Germany, Munich or Frankfurt would be the changing airport. There would be a passport check at the UK airport, but then where? Even entering the transit at the changing airport? I ask this because the layover time would be one hour there and I do not want to miss the connecting flight to my destination.

Comment: There is no passport control when leaving the UK. There is a passport control when entering the Schengen Area in Germany.

Comment: Note that "EU" is not the important part here, but Schengen area is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you arrive in Germany, you will go through passport control and transfer from the international area to the domestic one. In most cases, there is no security and you can just walk to your departure gate once you have cleared passport control.

How long this will take, is hard to predict and depends on your specific passport time of day, airline, terminal, etc. Things go a lot faster if you can use the automated passport lanes, but again, that depends on your passport and availability at your specific entry point.

One hour is on the tight side. If it's a single booking the airline will take care of you and put you on the next available flight for free.

Comment: Agreed, Just one point to add. I've done a 50 minute intra-to-extra Schengen transfer in Munich and can say it was more than enough. Of course this is if there is no delay on the origin flight.